# WCF what's is maximum value of timeout?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

i'm new in WCF(i've started learninig it today:)).

What's is maximum vaue of *Timeout arguments value in binding? Is it possible to setup it infinity?

```
<netTcpBinding>
        <binding  name="VeryLargeDataTcpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000000" transferMode="Streamed" closeTimeout="02:00:00" openTimeout="02:00:00" receiveTimeout="02:00:00" sendTimeout="02:00:00"  />
</netTcpBinding>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of OpenTimeout, SendTimeout and ReceiveTimout are validated with the internal TimeoutHelper method:

```
public static bool IsTooLarge(TimeSpan timeout)
{
    return ((timeout > MaxWait) && (timeout != Infinite));
}
```

Where MaxWait is defaulted in the Binding Ctor to

```
TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2147483647.0);
```

Which I believe is almost 25 days?

Comment: +1 for relating it to MaxWait and for `Infinite`.  Please, dear OP, don't use infinite or set it to 25 days...

Comment: It helps setting these TimeOut values to large numbers when you are debuggin both your client & server in VS, otherwise you don't have much time when you are investigating your variables in the debugger and the timeout occurs.