# What is the maximum value for timeout attributes in httpbinding in WCF

Tags: wpf, wcf

My config setting is as below.

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <!-- This binding is used when connecting to services secured using SSL (e.g. when accessible over internet/WAN) -->
        <binding name="SecuredBasicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="10675199.02:48:05.4775807"
          openTimeout="10675199.02:48:05.4775807" receiveTimeout="10675199.02:48:05.4775807" sendTimeout="10675199.02:48:05.4775807"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
```

I want to set maximum value for closetimeout,opentimeout..etc..
I got this value 10675199.02:48:05.4775807 from below url.but it didnt work.

[How can I set the receiveTimeout and sendTimeout to infinity with this WCF contact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178300/how-can-i-set-the-receivetimeout-and-sendtimeout-to-infinity-with-this-wcf-conta)

what is the max value which can be set for timeout?

Comment: I don't know the answer directly but I would like to advice you to think twice about doing so. What is the purpose? Want to wait infinitely for an "answer".

Comment: What didn't work actually? Compile time error? run time error?

Comment: actually some of my services are returning timeout expection,so want to set maxvalue of timeout thats the goal

Comment: I should not want to set it to a maximum. How long is that? And you are going to wait for a maximum value? Consider setting it to a realistic value depending on the lengthiness of the operation. Maybe 1 or 5 minutes is already a lot IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227323/wcf-whats-is-maximum-value-of-timeout) is stating that the max timeout is almost 25 days. Good luck with that! :p

As i mentioned before consider setting it to a realistic timespan and take appropriate actions when the response is timed-out.

Answer (score 0):

The max timeout value is the max value of a signed 32 bit integer: 2147483647